# Sampling a set of vectors of features in order to obtain "uniform" histograms for every feature

Tags: algorithm, matlab, histogram, sampling

I have a matrix of m vectors (samples) of n values (features), where m ~ 10^6, n = 20, and all the features have value in [0,1].

If I compute histograms for each of the features, those are quite different. I compute a simple 10 bins histogram, and I can see that for some histograms only a few bins (even two) contain all of the samples, some are skewed gaussian and some other are approximately uniform.

I would like to sample a subset of those vectors, in order to have a "uniform" distribution for all of the features. 
This basically means that I would like to have approximatively the same number of elements for each bin that is not already empty. 
A reasonable minimum of elements for this subset would be ~100.

My language of choice is MATLAB, but I am more interested to know if there is an algorithm that I could use, than to actual code (on which I can work myself).

Comment: My usual approach with problem that I know are going to be tricky and would require optimization is to code them in a straight forward way and only then try to optimize. You might start understanding the problem better find a different approach, divide and conquer. Maybe start with `h = histogram(...)`, h contains some good information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to build an approximation to the distribution of values along each feature — or fit an analytical distribution function — and then weight each sample accordingly.

```
vfNormValues = randn(1, 10000); % Samples from Normal distribution with mu=1, sigma=0

fMean = 0; mean(vfNormValues);
fStd = 1; std(vfNormValues);
vfWeights = 1./normpdf(vfNormValues, fMean, fStd); % Assume the underlying distribution is Normal
vfSamples = randsample(vfNormValues, 8000, true, vfWeights); % Weighted random sample with replacement

figure;
subplot(1, 2, 1);
hist(vfNormValues);
title('Original samples');
subplot(1, 2, 2);
hist(vfSamples);
title('Weighted re-sampling');
```

[image: Resampling from analytical distribution]
As you can see, the analytical approach might lead to oversampling of outliers.

Alternatively you can use a fully empirical distribution estimate, via a histogram:

```
nNumBins = floor(sqrt(numel(vfNormValues)));
[vnCounts, ~, vnBin] = histcounts(vfNormValues, nNumBins); % Set number of bins according to desired accuracy
vfBinWeights = 1./(vnCounts ./ sum(vnCounts));
vfWeights = vfBinWeights(vnBin);
```

And then perform a weighted sample with replacement, as before.
[image: Resampling with empirical distribution]

You will then need to work out how to combine the distributions for the several features. Under the assumption of statistical independence, you can simply combine the weights along each feature to use the marginal distribution. If the features are not statistically independent, then you will have to build a 20-dimensional histogram.

Comment: Could you explain more about the 20-dimensional histogram? My features are statistically dependent.

Comment: The 20-d histogram would be a 20-dimensional tensor, where each dimension corresponds to one of your feature spaces. You could use `histcounts` to perform automatic binning, calling it in a `for` loop over the 20 feature dimensions. That will tell you in which bin along each dimension a given sample falls. You can then use these 20 vectors as indices into your 20-dimensional space to build your big histogram, and estimate your dependent distribution and weights for each sample.

Comment: @DylanRichardMuir Quick question: in the empirical approach, the size of `vfWeights` is `nNumBins`, which no longer match the original data. So, how would you go about the weighted resampling? Thanks!